# Making Android Studio accessible across multiple users in ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I have a small problem. I have installed Android Studio on Ubuntu successfully. It is working fine. It is installed in the Admin account. I would like to make the studio available in the user account that I have created. Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem got solved. I hope this answers helps people who are facing a similar problem.

Solution to the problem:

1. Open terminal. Using sudo -i, become a root user and move the unzipped android studio folder into /opt

   `mv <your current folder location>/android-studio /opt`
2. Once the folder is moved, cd into `/usr/share/applications` folder
3. Open the text editor and create a file named `android-studio.desktop`. Enter the following code into the file and save it.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
           Version=1.0
           Type=Application
           Name=Android Studio
           Exec=bash -i "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
           Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
           Categories=Development;IDE;
           Terminal=false
           StartupNotify=true
           StartupWMClass=jetbrains-android-studio
           Name[en_GB]=android-studio.desktop
   ```
4. Now install the desktop file.
   `desktop-file-install android-studio.desktop`
5. Now android studio is accessible from the search menu
6. Close the terminal.
7. Launch android studio from the search menu (top left icon on the launcher)
8. Once android studio is running, you can right click on the icon on the launcher and lock it to the launcher.

Comment: It's `/usr/share/applications` in Mate